Remove gap between two graphs with shared axis
Objective
I want to generate a 'double ended' barchart, showing gained points (of some metric) vis-a-vis missed points, something like this:

Result so far
I managed to do this
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cohort": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"],
        "gained": [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52],
        "missed": [5, 8, 34, 21, 16, 22, 9, 7, 11],
    }
)

up = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_bar(color="blue")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(labels=False, title=None, ticks=False),
        y=alt.Y("gained:Q"),
    )
)
down = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_bar(color="red")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(labelAngle=0),
        y=alt.Y("missed:Q", scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)),
    )
)

alt.vconcat(up, down).resolve_scale(x="shared")

which generates this:

Is there any way I can remove the gap? Or perhaps go about it completely differently with Vega-Altair?

@r-beginners pointed me in the right direction, this does the trick:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cohort": [
            "start",
            "1st trimester",
            "2nd trimester",
            "3rd trimester",
            "delivery",
        ],
        "gained": [28, 55, 43, 11, 41],
        "missed": [5, 8, 34, 21, 16],
    }
)

WIDTH = 500
TEXT_OFFSET = 9

base_up = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(None), y=alt.Y("gained:Q").axis(None), text="gained:Q"
)
up = base_up.mark_bar() + base_up.mark_text(align="center", dy=-TEXT_OFFSET).properties(
    width=WIDTH
)

middle = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .encode(
        alt.X("cohort:N").axis(None),
        alt.Text("cohort:N"),
    )
    .mark_text()
    .properties(height=15, width=WIDTH)
)

base_down = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(None),
    y=alt.Y("missed:Q", scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)).axis(None),
    text="missed:Q",
)
down = base_down.mark_bar(color="red") + base_down.mark_text(
    align="center", dy=TEXT_OFFSET
).properties(width=WIDTH)

alt.vconcat(up, down, spacing=0).configure_view(strokeOpacity=0)



As for altair, I do not have a lot of experience. Is the graph you are looking for the vertical pyramid graph in the reference? If so, I would add an x-axis in the middle. Set the space between the graphs to 0.
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cohort": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"],
        "gained": [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52],
        "missed": [5, 8, 34, 21, 16, 22, 9, 7, 11],
    }
)

up = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_bar(color="blue")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(None),
        y=alt.Y("gained:Q"),
    )
)
middle = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    alt.X('cohort:N').axis(None),
    alt.Text('cohort:N'),
).mark_text().properties(height=15)

down = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_bar(color="red")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("cohort:N").axis(None),
        y=alt.Y("missed:Q", scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)),
    )
)

alt.vconcat(up, middle, down, spacing=0)#.resolve_scale(x="shared")



thanks @r-beginners. Setting spacing=0 actually closes the gap (no pun intended) but still not quite what I was looking for.
